# Rollback in Git

Tags: git, rollback

Question about doing a rollback in git:

Let's say the git SHA of the commit I want to rollback to is: `12345`.

I tried:

```
git checkout 12345
git checkout -b rollback
git push origin rollback
```

Then, when I attempt to compare 'rollback' with master, it says there are no differences - why?

UPDATE: I compared master branch and rollback branch using Github and found no differences.

I found that the following works:

```
git checkout -b current-state-master
git checkout master
git checkout 12345
git push origin -f
```

I see why the second one works, but I don't know why the first approach did not work.

Comment: Could you tell us, which commands you use in order to compare `rollback` with `master`? Please provide a complete minimal working example with the outcome and the expected outcome.

Comment: To which commit do the two branches `master` and `rollback` on Github point to? Which SHAs? What happens if you do a `git diff master rollback` locally?

Answer (score 2):

This is my take:

```
git checkout 12345        #This checks out the commit with SHA starting with 12345
                          #You're in detached HEAD state and
                          #you're in no way related to any branch
git checkout -b rollback  #This creates a new branch starting from the current HEAD,
                          #which is 12345.
git push origin rollback  #This updates branch rollback on origin with the 
                          #local branch rollback
```

If the HEAD of the `master` branch differs from the commit with SHA 12345 `git diff rollback master` will generate some output. I don't know what you're doing in your case, but the problem should lie somewhere else.

A bit more succinct: If `git diff master 12345` produces output, then `git diff master rollback` will as well. `git diff rollback 12345` will not.

Following this, your second example will work as well as it is only missing the line, which gives the detached HEAD the name `rollback`.

So my answer would be:
Your problem can not originate from the lines of code you've given.

See [git checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) and [git branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

Comment: I agree with you that Josh Reback's 3 lines of Git code should not be causing problems.  But can you suggest a reason for this?  Your response does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

To follow from Tim Biegeleisen's answer, your first snippet can be corrected like so:

```
git checkout -b rollback
git reset 12345
git push origin rollback
```

This will leave "rolled back" commits in the index; use `reset --hard` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

What about the simplest one:

```
git revert 12345
```

or

```
git revert HEAD~3
```

or

```
git revert -n master~5..master~2
```

Furthermore doing things in a repo via `git reset ..` would result in a non forwarding history which will produce pain for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard 12345

git push origin master -f
```

**warning！：** The "--hard" parameter will ignore all the local modifies .